# Background at passowordBox in the uwp

Tags: xamarin, uwp, background, controltemplate, passwordbox

I am using the uwp component password box (XAMARIN) and set a certain image as the background, but when I click on the box, the background changes. I would like to keep the background static.

```
   <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordUser">
            <PasswordBox.Background  >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Login/campo-senha.png"/>
            </PasswordBox.Background>
</PasswordBox>
```

PasswordBox.Background before clicked

[image]

PasswordBox.Background after clicked

[image]

So I would like the background to remain as I set it, always even when I click click on the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check  `PasswordBox` style xaml, the password background has point over and focused status. so you need re-write the following resource with the  ImageBrush that contains the same image source. You could place the follow resource in the page resource or application resource base on your design.

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundPointerOver" ImageSource="/Assets/bgimg.png" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" ImageSource="/Assets/bgimg.png" />
```